# How to use Stream.io and Webhook in a C# Console App?

Tags: c#, webhooks, getstream-io

I want to know a simple example which will use `getstream.io` and `webhook` services to process activities on a social networking site. Actually, I am building an app which processes interactions of users as Like, Comment, Share etc. Now I want to use Stream.io to ease the task.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What approaches have you considered so far? Receiving webhooks will involve an internet-facing web application to process the HTTP requests. .NET Core, ServiceStack could be a useful starting point. From there you can work with the Stream [docs](https://getstream.io/docs/#realtime-webhooks) to receive, parse and process the webhook data.

Comment: I have no idea of how I can connect my CosmosDB where I am storing my Feeditems with the getstream.io and store the activities back. I have gone through the documentation, I got how the things can be organised but my confusion is in the case of interaction between the getstream.io and the storage. For example, in case I LIKE a FeedItem, how to interact with the storage to store that like activity. I don't know how this interacts with my storage     **user_feed_1 = client.feed('user', '1')**

Comment: That seems like a separate question to one of how to receive and process webhooks. Briefly, the process of combining data stored in your backend with the Stream feed is referred to as [enrichment](https://getstream.io/docs/#enrichment) in the documentation. You could also step through the [Cabin example](https://getstream.io/cabin/) (in JavaScript / Node) to get an idea of the how enrichment works in a real app.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [this piece of code](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-dotnet-client/blob/master/ApiAiSDK.Tests/ApiAiTest.cs) yet?

Once you’ve installed the NuGet package, sending and receiving response from the Dialogflow endpoint shouldn’t be too much of an effort.

You should be able to convert the above linked example into a simple hello world console application and see the results instantly.

Hope this helps!